# Connect to AP using push WPS

Tags: wifi, dhcp, wpa, wps

I tried accordingly to existing topics (in SE or other websites) to connect to an AP with button WPS. `wps_pbc` associate successfully, `dhclient` gives me an internal IP successfully, but `firefox` loads no pages at all

So, where is the truth between all those commands?

```bsh
systemctl start/stop systemd-resolved.service
wpa_cli wps_pbc
wpa_cli interface wlo1
systemctl start/stop NetworkManager.service
dhclient wlo1
ip addr flush dev wlo1
ifdown/up wlo1
ping 1.1.1.1
firefox google.com
```

Comment: Not much to go on - you push a button and it doesn't work. I presume the button in a router - does the router work otherise? And is wIfi hardware you' using to connect to the AP, is it compatible with the WPS on the router?

Comment: The router works just fine, the hardware works fine with other methods than this one (CLI)